# rails 5 bootstrap 4 cuztomization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

Just upgraded to bootstrap 4.
In the old version I was using `@import bootstrap` on my app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss file and thus customizations worked fine.

Now, following the getbootstrap.com Get Started guide, I have included `@import bootstrap` in my application.scss and customizations have stopped working.

Here's my gemfile;

```
    gem 'rails',                   '5.1.4'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.7.3'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.6'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '1.0.0'
gem 'puma',                    '3.9.1'
gem 'uglifier',                '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',              '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.7.0'
gem 'coffee-script-source',    '1.8.0'
gem 'letsencrypt_plugin',      '~> 0.0.10'
gem 'etsy',                    '~> 0.3.2'
gem 'bootstrap',               '~> 4.0'
gem 'sprockets-rails',         '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.1'
gem 'popper_js',               '~> 1.12', '>= 1.12.9'
```

My application.scss file:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 */

 @import "bootstrap"
```

Here's what I'm trying to get to work in custom.scss:

```
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color: $light-gray!important;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аfter `@import`, a semicolon is missing. Make sure that the variable `$light-gray` is also defined. I think `@import` with bootstrap 4 version works pretty the same as for bootstrap 3.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Roman! That did it :) I did have to add  *= require_tree . (against what bootstrap recommended, but it's still working as expected)